# How to differentiate domains in awstats that share a single access.log file?

Tags: awstats

I run 5 domains in a webserver that share the access.log file.

I configure awstats, creating one awstats.example.org.conf file per each domain, but every one gives me the same stats (cause the same log file).

Is there any way of configuring awstats to just ignore all the other loglines except for the configured domain?

This is one of my apache log files:

```
10.234.xxx.xxx - - [08/Feb/2011:10:29:48 +0100] "GET /some-page HTTP/1.1" 200 30132 "http://www.example.org/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/9.0.597.84 Safari/534.13" sec:0 usec:25405
```

Thanks in advance, Simon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, set the [siteDomain](http://awstats.sourceforge.net/docs/awstats_config.html#SiteDomain) and specify where the vhost appears in the logfiles